# Adobe PDF Distributed Form- changing the collection email mailbox

Tags: pdf, adobe, distributed

When using Adobe PDF distributed forms, how does one update the email mailbox to which the responses are sent?  It seems to be using my personal email address as the default but this form's data needs to go to a different mailbox.
In other words, I can't figure out how to change the return address.
I do not see this question anywhere on the web.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would change the Identity preferences before Distributing the form.

The eMail address for returning is taken from that preference setting.